# Couldn't find module: modue name for architecture: arm64

Tags: ios, module, 64-bit, appcelerator, appcelerator-titanium

I am trying to work with the Linea SDK to scan things in my app. I created a module and added it to my app. However, whenever I try to call the module in my code I get this error: 
Couldn't find module: us.netpark.module.linea for architecture: arm64.

I have run all the things to check to make sure the module was built correctly and I have confirmed that the module says that it has the arm64 architecture by running this command:
xcrun lipo -info build/libus.netpark.module.linea.a

And the results are:
Architectures in the fat file: build/libus.netpark.module.linea.a are: armv7 i386 x86_64 arm64.

I have also used this link: https://github.com/FokkeZB/ti-64.
The results of that module are the same it says that the module I have built has the arm64 architecture available.

Here is my module list in my tiapp.xml:

```
    <modules>
        <module platform="iphone">us.netpark.module.epson</module>
        <module platform="iphone">us.netpark.module.captuvosl22</module>
        <module platform="iphone">us.netpark.module.linea</module>
        <module platform="iphone">ti.map</module>
        <module platform="android">ti.map</module>
        <module platform="android">com.appcelerator.apm</module>
        <module platform="iphone">com.appcelerator.apm</module>
        <module platform="iphone">com.appcelerator.urlSession</module>
    </modules>
```

Additionally here is my plist info pertinent to this question:

```
    <dict>
        <key>UISupportedExternalAccessoryProtocols</key>
        <array>
            <string>com.honeywell.scansled.protocol.decoder</string>
            <string>com.honeywell.scansled.protocol.msr</string>
            <string>com.honeywell.scansled.protocol.pm</string>
            <string>com.epson.escpos</string>
            <string>com.datecs.linea.pro.bar</string>
            <string>com.datecs.linea.pro.msr</string>
        </array>
        <array>
            <string>armv7</string>
            <string>arm64</string>
        </array>
    </dict>
```

Any help would be much appreciated cause I don't know what I am doing wrong, but it seems like the module was built correctly, but it isn't being accepted by appcelerator. I have no trouble compiling my app with the module included, but I only get the error after I hit a window where I am trying to use the new module.

I am using Xcode 7.3, iOS 9.3, and Titanium SDK 5.2.2.

Comment: Happening to me too right now. Same ENV

Comment: We were able to get this to work, but I couldn't tell you why it started working. It just started working and hasn't stopped since... It was all very strange.